# Get theme's primary text color on runtime

Tags: android, android-theme

Suppose that I have a custom theme on my app that inherits from either `Holo`, `Holo.Light` or `Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`. I don't know from which one it will inherit until runtime.

I want to retrieve in runtime the current theme's **primary text color**.

For example, if I know the current theme is `Holo`, the corresponding color would be `primary_text_dark` and I *could* do the following in order to retrieve the theme's primary text color.

```
getResources().getColor(android.R.color.primary_text_dark)
```

But I don't know which of the three will be, so I need a way to, at least, know the name of the theme's parent name.

Answer (score 0):

It will always return the theme your your current activity. If you would call `setTheme()` you could get another value of cause. I hope that helps, but I guess there is no directly way to read the theme name anyway try working with `getTheme()`.